# batch doen't read text file till save it first

Tags: batch-file

My code stops at line 3 in the .dat file ,but when i save the .dat file it reads all the lines and work properly why this happening and what to do??

this is code my data contain Latina characters and symbols.

```
@ECHO Off
SET "sourcedir=D:\yyyyy\Orgin_file_Ma\MA_SMS"
SET "destdir=D:\llllll\STG_file_Ma"
FOR %%f IN ("%sourcedir%\*.dat") DO > "%destdir%\%%~nf.txt" (
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%%f") DO (
set Typ=SMS
  ECHO %%a^|!Typ!
 )
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively the same question you asked yesterday.

An answer cannot be provided unless you change your code to something that works; try this:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "SOURCEDIR=D:\yyyyy\Orgin_file_Ma\MA_SMS"
SET "DESTDIR=D:\llllll\STG_file_Ma"
SET "TYP=SMS"
FOR %%F IN ("%SOURCEDIR%\*.dat") DO FOR /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS=" %%A IN ("%%F"
) DO >"%DESTDIR%\%%~nF.txt" ECHO %%A^|%TYP%
```

After confirming the structure of the above script is correct, add it to your question above by way of the **edit** facility and provide much more information on those `dat` files.

Depending upon those `dat` files it is likely that `ECHO` may not be the correct command to use.

Comment: Hi compo the real challenge is why the script work just fine when i save the .dat file that mean the csript has no problem the problem with .dat file i think,is there any command to save the .dat file in the beginning of the above script.

Comment: The real challenge is in you understanding that we need information about the `dat` files. The `.dat` extension does not provide us with any information about the layout, character set, structure, encoding or even an idea of the program which may read from or write to that file. You are the only person who can do that, _by appending that information as an **edit** to your opening question_.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your helpful answers i learned a lot,i solved my problem by using Powershell instead of batch.